# Is there any way to view compressed files?

Tags: compression, zip, winrar, viewer

I don't mean decompressed, I mean like open the compressed WinRAR or zip file as is (compressed)

I want to view the gibberish zipped/Winrared file. without decompression.

OS: Windows 10 Pro

Thanks

edit: Got my answer, Thanks for the help! sry for being unclear

Comment: What do you want to view about the file? The binary compressed data? Or the "normal" contents of the file without having to decompress it first? Right now it is unclear what you are asking. Please use the EDIT button to add relevant information including what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: Command: `7z l abc.zip`

Comment: Please add an OS tag. E.g. under Linux/MacOS, you can look at the uncompressed hex data (if that is what you want) with `hexdump`.

Comment: I want to view the binary compressed data!

Comment: What's wrong with just opening it in a hex editor?  It still isn't clear what the issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compressed file will look like rubbish (except for entry names in .zip archives for instance). You can open it in any text editor. If the contents are *not* looking random, the compression was very unefficient - or there was no compression at all (e.g. format "Store" in .zip archives).

Comment: That's exactly what I am asking how to view the rubbish?

Comment: Right click > open with and choose any text editor like notepad ++ ?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to view the contents of a compressed file without extracting/decompressing it. That all depends on the type of compressed file it is and which applications can support it. There are probably hundreds of different compressed file types and thousands of applications that can read them, so an exact answer to this question isn't possible.

If it's a .ZIP file, the easiest in Windows XP and later, if Explorer is the default application for opening .ZIP files, would be to simply double click it.

Alternatively, you can install a 3rd party application like WinRAR or 7zip to view the contents if it's a common compressed file type.